# Parameters are not passed on Http post request?

Tags: ios, swift, http, post, request

Hai I am trying to pass some parameters of string in Http post request. I have created a dictionary and then converted that dictionary to data and set as  httpBody.But when I looked on our server nothing has been passd I mean parameters are empty.Why? What mistake i am doing?Please help me to find out.Thanks in advance.

```
func receiptValidation(productId:String,requestFrom:String)
{
    let SUBSCRIPTION_SECRET = "mySecretKey"
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let receiptPath = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL?.path
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: receiptPath!){
        var receiptData:NSData?
        do {
            receiptData = try NSData(contentsOf: Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL!, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.alwaysMapped)
        }
        catch{
            print("ERROR: " + error.localizedDescription)
        }
        //let receiptString = receiptData?.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        let base64encodedReceipt = receiptData?.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.endLineWithCarriageReturn)

        print(base64encodedReceipt!)
        let requestDictionary = ["receipt-data":base64encodedReceipt!,"password":SUBSCRIPTION_SECRET]

        guard JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(requestDictionary) else {  print("requestDictionary is not valid JSON");  return }
        do {
            let requestData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestDictionary)
            let requestDataString=String(describing: requestData)
            let URLForApplication:String = String(format:"%@/api/validate-receipt-data",opcodeDetails["apiProxyBaseUrl"]!)  // this works but as noted above it's best to use your own trusted server
            SwiftyBeaver.info("URLForApplication Path:\n\(URLForApplication)")
            let url:URL! = URL.init(string: URLForApplication)
            var request = URLRequest.init(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            let configure = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
            session1=URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: applicationDelegate.application, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

            var postString =
                ["receiptData":requestDataString,
                 "deviceType":"IOS",
                 "subscriberId":encodeString(normalString: defaults.array(forKey: "userDetails")?.first as! String),
                 "password":encodeString(normalString: defaults.array(forKey: "userDetails")?.last as! String),
                 "productId":encodeString(normalString: productId ),
                 "code":opcodeDetails["opCode"]!]
            do {
                request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postString, options: .prettyPrinted) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            let task = session1?.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                if let data = data , error == nil {
                    do {
                        let appReceiptJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
                        print("success. here is the json representation of the app receipt: \(appReceiptJSON)")
                        // if you are using your server this will be a json representation of whatever your server provided
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        print("json serialization failed with error: \(error)")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("the upload task returned an error: \(error)")
                }
            }
            task?.resume()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("json serialization failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

and what error i am getting is `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}`

Comment: Your code aren't readable, please format it, so at least someone can read it.

Comment: Did you try to print content of
```try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postString, options: .prettyPrinted) ```?

Comment: It prints as some bytes

Comment: The error seems coming from the response, not from the request itself. Try to print the response data using `String(data: response.data, using: .utf8)` to see what the server is actually returning.

Comment: When I see on server it looks like this ```PayloadLoggingFilter - Request : POST, /validate-receipt-data, {}```

Comment: Yep, so the server received the request, but likely threw some exception when processing it. Look in your error logs or examine the status code and body of the response.

Comment: Unrelated, but (a) your `configure` is not needed as you’re not using it at all; and (b) you generally shouldn’t be creating a new `URLSession` every time you perform a request anyway. It’s best to instantiate that once, up front, and use the same `URLSession` for all the requests.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t say, but I’m assuming you’re getting this error where you print “json serialization failed with error”. If so, CZ54 is right, that your response is obviously not JSON. So, where you print that error, also print the header and body  to see what the server actually returned, if anything:

```
print("response header:", response ?? "No response")
print("response body:", String(data: data, using: .utf8) ?? "No body")
```

The response header will include the status code (which should be something in the 200...299 range). If it’s not in that range, the status code will tell you the broad nature of the problem.

And regarding the response body, Sometimes (esp in development environments) if the server choked on something, it may return a HTML page outlining the nature of the problem (though, admittedly, in other cases, it only outputs the fact that there was an error, but not the details, and you’ll need to go into the server error logs to figure out what went wrong).

Looking at the specifics of the response, like above, is is your first step. Or you can achieve this by running the app on a simulator, and watching the request and the response in a tool like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). Once you get them up and running, these are great tools for inspecting requests and responses.

The next question is *why* the server generated the response that it did. As a general rule, while these sorts of problems can be a result of some server mistake, the more likely scenario is that the request wasn’t formed correctly and the server didn’t know how to handle it. Looking at the response (or looking at your server’s error logs) often provides good clues. But there’s no way anyone can help you on the basis of the information provided.

Comment: Actually My problem is parameters are not passed while I am requesting with Http Post method.         When I see on logs It is like this  ```[INFO ] 2019-12-26 07:06:27.657 c3f0ab24d7b94d6bad1ccdf78d856867 PayloadLoggingFilter - Request : POST, /validate-receipt-data, {}
[INFO ] 2019-12-26 07:06:27.657 c3f0ab24d7b94d6bad1ccdf78d856867 Util - Default int value is returned
[INFO ] 2019-12-26 07:06:27.658 c3f0ab24d7b94d6bad1ccdf78d856867 PayloadLoggingFilter - Response : {"status":"failure","statusCode":500,"message":"Invalid Parameters!"}. Total Time : 1 ms```

Comment: Yep, that’s exactly one of the scenarios I was contemplating when I suggested that the problem might be that “the request wasn’t formed correctly”. E.g., maybe your server was expecting the request to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. (BTW, that’s very common pattern, that requests are `x-www-form-urlencoded` and responses are JSON.) Or maybe the keys to your request were wrong. It could be any of a myriad of things, something we can’t deduce by just looking at the code that created the request. You need to confirm precisely what the server is expecting.

Comment: @PriyaSri  Your server log is saying that the response was `{"status":"failure","statusCode":500,"message":"Invalid Parameters!"}`, but obviously that’s not the response that the client received because it’s saying that the response wasn’t JSON. When you print the “response body” from the client, like I suggest in my answer, I bet you’ll find it’s not well-formed JSON (or else you wouldn’t have received that “JSON text did not start with array or object...” error. There something else in the response other than just that JSON...